# How does this code for BernoulliNB classifier works?

Tags: python, machine-learning, naivebayes

Can someone please explain what this code does? It's from the book "Introduction to Machine Learning with Python" on Bernoulli Naive Bayes classifier:

```
counts = {}
for label in np.unique(y):
    # iterate over each class
    # count (sum) entries of 1 per feature
    counts[label] = X[y == label].sum(axis=0)
print("Feature counts:\n", counts)
```

I don't understand what happens on line5.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use an example.

```
import numpy as np
X=np.array([[1,10],[2,20], [3,30], [4,40], [5,50], [6,60]])
y=np.array([11,22,33,11,22,11])
```

`np.unique(y)` is `[11,22,33]`

So label will successively be those.

When label is 11
`y==label` is `[11,22,33,11,22,11]==11` which is `[True,False,False,True,False,True]`
so `X[y==label]` is `X[[True,False,False,True,False,True]]` so it is a selection of rows 0, 3 and 5 of X. So `[[1,10],[4,40],[6,60]]`
`sum(axis=0)` sum that along axis 0, so `X[y==label].sum(axis=0)` is `[1+4+6,10+40,60]` = `[11,110]`
so `counts[11]=[11,110]`

Likewise, when label is 22, `y==label` is `[False,True,False,False,True,False]`, so `X[y==label]` is `[[2,20],[5,50]]` so `X[y==label].sum(axis=0)` is `[7,70]`, which is affected to `counts[22]`.

And when label is 33, `y==label` is just `[False,False,True,False,False,False]`, so `X[y==label]` is `[[3,30]]` so `X[y==label].sum(axis=0)` is `[3,30]` which is affected to `counts[33]`.

So at the end, if your X data are a list of k values, and y data a list of k classes, chosen among n possibilities, `counts` are, for each n possible classes, the k sums of the values of data matching that class.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the short code snippet, it seems like the variable `X` is a data frame, and when you do `X[y == label]`, it is filtering the data frame based on the condition where column `y` matches with the label.

Proceeding to the `.sum()`, it is taking the sum of the rows where column `y` has the value that matches the label. If this column happens to be a multi-dimensional array, it is taking the sum on the first axis, i.e. vertically.

Finally on the left hand side of the equal sign, it is adding this sum to the `counts` dictionary where the key is the label.